# Dystopian film involving a child assassin and floating city

Tags: story-identification, anime

Many years ago, on SBS (a TV channel in Australia), I saw the first half of a film, an not knowing the ending is frustrating as all hell.

Here's what I remember:

- It was an animated film, anime style.  Dystopian setting.  There was
  a floating city that was connected to the lower city by a massive
  tube. There were traps and security measures all along the tube to
  prevent people trying to climb it.
- There was a man, who worked as a doctor during the day, and was some 
  sort of assassin/bounty hunter at night.
- He adopted a little girl, who one night follows him out, finds out he's an assassin, gets attacked by his target and turns out to be an 
  amazingly coordinated killing machine.
- Later in the film, she and a friend try to climb the tube to get to the upper city. He friend gets killed (or at least grievously injured) by the traps on the tube, and she falls back down to the lower city.

That's about all I can remember for now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Battle Angel Alita or Gunnm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita)  One of my all time favorites.

Comment: Also, he wasn't an assassin, he was a bounty hunter.